# how to load a variable in a for loop or linq

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I have values assigned to a variable as follows:

```
private string[] numbers = new string[] {"1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5"};
```

then i take my number variable and i filter through each as follows

```
 protected void display()
    {

        bonusdiv.Visible = true; 
        panelbonus.InnerHtml = "";

        foreach (string option in numbers)
        {
            string optiontext = option;
            if (option.Length == 1)
            {
                optiontext = "" + optiontext;
            }

            if (panelBonusselections.Contains(option))
            {
                panelbonus.InnerHtml += "<input name=\"_bonus1_" + option + "\" id=\"/_bonus1_" + option + "\" type=\"submit\" value=\"" + optiontext + "\" class=\"optionselected\"/>";
            }
            else
            {
                panelbonus.InnerHtml += "<input name=\"_bonus1_" + option + "\" id=\"/_bonus1_" + option + "\" type=\"submit\" value=\"" + optiontext + "\" class=\"option\"/>";
            }

        }
    }
```

now the question i pose is,i want to assign the values mentioned above into a single instance,something like

```
numbers=[5]; //but this must still use the same logic as above to store the values from 1 up to 5.Then how do i cater for this change in my foreach loop?
```

will it be something like the bellow?

> int numbers=[5]

```
for (i=1,i>5, i++) {
  foreach (string option in numbers)
        {
            string optiontext = option;
            if (option.Length == 1)
            {
                optiontext = "" + optiontext;
            }

            if (panelBonusselections.Contains(option))
            {
                panelbonus.InnerHtml += "<input name=\"_bonus1_" + option + "\" id=\"/_bonus1_" + option + "\" type=\"submit\" value=\"" + optiontext + "\" class=\"optionselected\"/>";
            }
            else
            {
                panelbonus.InnerHtml += "<input name=\"_bonus1_" + option + "\" id=\"/_bonus1_" + option + "\" type=\"submit\" value=\"" + optiontext + "\" class=\"option\"/>";
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. By the pseudo code `int numbers=[5]` do you want to create an `int[]` of `{1,2,3,4,5}` or a `string[]` like `{"1", "2"....,"5"}` and accordingly for `numbers=[12]`? Or am I completly wrong?

Comment: correct,i want a string[], i just dont want to enter it in everytime like numbers={"1","2".... etc} is there a way that i can just tell the string numbers must be["5"] like how when you loop through an array type of thing. so like just say in the future i want to add up till 20 numbers i dont want to go type in numbers ={"1","2",...."18","19","20"} i just want to be able to say numbers=[5] can become numbers=[20]

Comment: If you're going to generate `numbers` you may as well ditch it altogether and replace `foreach (string option in numbers)` by a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a sequence and [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) to project it to strings:

```
string[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Or as a method:

```
string[] GetNumbersStringArray(int length)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, length).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: do i need to change anything in my display method?

Comment: @Jesse not as far as I can see, `numbers` is still a `string[]`. (you may of course shorten the method a little since the `if` and `else` part look quite similar except the `"selected"` at the end, but that's a matter of taste)